# Python command line equivalent to Bash "fc" editing of many past commands?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been new to Python for years, but trying to get traction.

I run Python 3 without the GUI, i.e., from a Cygwin bash shell by issuing `Python`.  My `~/.inputrc` is configured to let me edit commands using Vim for many applications, e.g., Bash, Octave, Python.

In bash, I can edit many past commands at a time using (say) `fc -10 0`.  However, it is a built-in command, not readline.

Is there something similar in Python, allowing me to use Vim to edit a swath of past commands?  I am finding it quite limiting to experiment and learn code patterns/syntax without this.

Comment: there is not, but you can write a script file using your editor and run that

Comment: Try looking here: https://symbols.hotell.kau.se/2017/12/10/about-ipython/

Comment: OMG, Cygwin. Take that thing out back and shoot it! WSL made that obsolete, check it out. Also, Windows Terminal Preview rocks, get both of them for free from the Windows Store.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: I do that too, in Matlab (since it no longer uses readline on Windows).  I selfishly want the convenience of Bash's `fc`.  Lazy me.

Comment: @Red Cricket: I looked at that page.  It lets you set the editor.  But does it have a counterpart to Bash's `fc`, allowing one to edit swaths of historical commands?

Comment: @Mike Slinn: I looked at WSL in the past few years.  I thought it would be too time consuming to get all the functionality in the Cygwin package repository, including X-windows.

Comment: For X, use GWSL. Instant setup. WSL is far, far beyond Cygwin. I suffered through Cygwin for years. So glad to have WSL. You can install WSL without removing Cygwin, and you can remove WSL without destroying the rest of your system. Check it out.

Comment: Hmm, I will take another look.  Apart from time, however, one of the reasons stuck with Cygwin is because of its one-stop shop for packages. Python, Gvim, Octave, LaTeX and its packages (and probably the same for the previous apps), ImageMagick, various PDF swiss army knives, and many things that I don't recall just now.  Would WSL and GWSL provide this convenience?